# Issue with getting Real Client IP Address when load balancer is in place

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am not able to get real client IP address using `X-Forwarded-For` header.  My application is built on Dot net core 1.1 not 3.0 which is latest. And we have load balancer set up to distribute the load.

And I have implemented code as mentioned in below MSDN article.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-1.1#forwarded-headers-middleware-options
```

this is article used for implementation

### sample code

1) Configure services with forward options

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
            services.AddMvc();
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders =
                    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
                options.ForwardLimit = 2;
                options.KnownProxies.Add(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("123.111.11.88"));
                //options.KnownProxies.Clear();
                //options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
            });
        }
```

here 123.111.11.88 is sample Load balancer IP address.

2) Configure method changes as below:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
           --------
            app.UseForwardedHeaders();
           -------
      }
```

3) Code to read headers as below:

```
 string realClientIP = GetHeaderValueAs<string>("X-Cluster-Client-Ip");

 public T GetHeaderValueAs<T>(string headerName)
        {
            StringValues values;

            Request.Headers.TryGetValue(headerName, out values);
            if (!StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(values))
            {
                var rawValues = values.ToString();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawValues))
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(values.ToString(), typeof(T));
            }

            return default(T);
        }
```

queries:

1) is this right way to get real client IP with dot net core 1.1 since I could see that MSDN article is for dot net core 3.0 and there is no reference article for core 1.0.

2) Is it possible to get result using custom headers and how it can be done if possible ?

3) Please let me know if there is any other way ?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**. Change your code to

```
 services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
  
              options.KnownProxies.Clear();
             options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        });
```

**Step 2**. add ContextAccessor

```
 services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

**Step 3**. Use IActionContextAccessor to get the IP like the below method

```
public static string GetClientIp(this IActionContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        var remoteIp = contextAccessor.ActionContext.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

        if (remoteIp.IsIPv4MappedToIPv6)
        {
            remoteIp = remoteIp.MapToIPv4();
        }

        return remoteIp.ToString();
    }
```